# Coloring polygons according to total sum of attributes within polygon?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have point data about wind turbines across a country with information about the power output. Second shapefile I have is the country state borders (polygon). I now want to color the state polygons according to the total power of the turbines in the polygon.

How can I do that with QGIS?

Comment: you can do this with the "Processing Toolbox" and then "Join Attributes by location (summary)"

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that :

you choose your **country** layer, then **layer properties/categorized** as 'column' you use the following expression :

```
 intersecting_geom_sum('turbines_layer','power')
```

You build and fine-tune the classes of your symbology and you're done.

*To adapt to your data stucture/naming ...*